# New paper claims quantum polylog time attack on AES

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography, quantum-cryptanalysis, quantum-computing

It is well known that Grover's algorithm can solve AES in $O(\sqrt{n})$ time, which is why symmetric key length needs to be double to maintain their security level in the face of a quantum adversary.  [A recent eprint paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2022/948) claims there exists a polylog time attack on AES (or searching unsorted sets in general) using a quantum computer.  Can someone familiar with quantum computing comment on the validity of this attack?

Comment: I posted a comment earlier linking to a tweet of Ward Beullens apparently refuting the applicability of the paper. Ward's comment was however apparently based on a misunderstanding. So who knows at the moment.

Comment: I am relinking to the twitter comment by Ward Beullens and subsequent discussion, so those who may be interested can click if they so wish. https://twitter.com/WardBeullens/status/1551160115084115969

Comment: withdrawn papers can still be accessed on eprint. Just click "See all versions" https://eprint.iacr.org/archive/2022/948/20220722:134301

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I concur with Xavier Bonnetain per lamba's answer, but can add a bit more flesh to what is going on.

Working through the proposed algorithm with an $n$-bit search space, looking for a solution $x$ to $f(x)=y$, the idea is to first of all prepare $n/2$ banks of $n$ single qubit registers in full superposition (e.g. by using $n^2/2$ Hadamard gates). For each bank of registers, we then use another $n$ single qubit registers to compute the function $f$ (which is taken to be a block cipher with variable key taken from the input register and operating on a fixed plaintext in the cryptanalytic example, but I see no great reason not to apply the general Grover question). Thus we have $n/2$ copies of the state
$$\frac1{2^{n/2}}\sum_{x=0}^{2^n-1}|x\rangle|f(x)\rangle.$$
In fact each state will only need two distinct bits of $f(x)$, so the above could be done with a single call to $f(x)$ rather than $n/2$ calls. If we write $S_i$ for the $i$th bank of registers we now do a single iteration of Grover's algorithm looking for solutions $x$ such that $f_{2i,2i+1}(x)=y_{2i,2i+1}$ where subscripting denotes considering only the index bits (i.e. we look for all $x$ such that the $2i$th and $(2i+1)$th bits of $f(x)$ match the corresponding bits of $y$). This is a 2-bit search space and we expect Grover's algorithm to succeed in a single iteration and roughly 1/4 of our search space to match the condition.

Each of our $n/2$ banks now consists of roughly $2^{n/2-1}$ states in balanced superposition with other states effectively of zero amplitude:
$$S_i=\frac1{2^{n/2-1}}\sum_{x=0\atop f_{2i,2i+1}(x)=y_{2i,2i+1}}^{2^n-1}|x\rangle|f(x)\rangle$$
note that the only $x$ values to appear in all $n/2$ superpositions are the values with $f(x)=y$. There does not seem to be a critical dependency on the division into pairs of bits here; one could for example divide into $n/k$ banks and consider sextuples of bits and use $O(2^{k/2})$ Grover iterations.

The author now observes that if we could take the [Hadamard product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)) (componentwise product) of the amplitudes of each value of $x$ across the $n/2$ banks, then all non-causal values of $x$ will have at least one bank where the amplitude is zero (i.e. at least one bank where $f(x)$ fails to match two of the bits of $y$). In this case, the only non-zero amplitudes would be the values of $x$ that we seek and measurement should recover them. This implicitly assumes a renormalisation of amplitudes within the Hadamard product.

Those with a background in quantum computation will have a worry at this point, as the Hadamard product is not reversible and so not a [unitary transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_transformation_(quantum_mechanics)). The paper however notes that the Hadamard product is one of a number of matrix operations covered in the paper [Compiling basic linear algebra subroutines for quantum computers](https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.10394) by Zhao et al. Treating the Zhao paper as a black box resource for computing renormalised Hadamard products then gives the result. However, I believe that the Zhao paper does not quite work in this way. Hadamard products are computed in the Zhao paper by embedding the problem in a larger unitary system and computing an approximation to the Hadamard product. The amplitude of the causal solution is super exponentially small (roughly $2^{-n^2/4}$) and will be lost in the noise of the approximation. Perhaps more precisely, to approximate the answer sufficiently accurately will require an exponentially growing set of resources. I intend to read the Zhao paper more deeply to expand on this.

Comment: The Zhao paper is about embedding matrices into quantum computations so arbitrary matrix operations can be computed on those matrices. The Hadamard transform in this case is *of the quantum computation itself*. These are not compatible as the quantum computation does not follow the embedding.

Comment: Compare: observing that if only a computer could put itself in a time loop, the halting problem would become solvable - then observing that there are video games involving time loops - then concluding the halting problem is solvable.

Answer (score 16):

There is an answer on the PQC mailing list by Xavier Bonnetain (https://groups.google.com/a/list.nist.gov/g/pqc-forum/c/orySwdhmjH8/m/ScE8G_ajBgAJ) which I will copy below:

> The algorithm begins but doing many grover searches in the key space
> with the predicate "Does the encryption of M with K matches the
> expected encryption on bits (2i,2i+1)?" Assuming the proportion of
> keys that fulfill this property is exactly 1/4, we obtain, in 1 grover
> iteration, the exact quantum superposition of all matching keys. Now,
> the idea is that the correct key is the only one that appears in all
> the superpositions. The Hadamard product allows to get the
> interstection of 2 quantum superpositions. Thus, by iterating Hadamard
> products, we can recover the key.
>
> There are 2 main problems:
>
> - in the algorithm, computing a Hadamard product is not efficient, here it would be exponential.
> - The claimed result is not possible: this algorithm would efficiently break any block cipher (and probably, beyond that, almost
>   all cryptography) in black box. This violates lower bounds on the
>   quantum security of the ideal cipher.
>
> To summarize, any attack, classical or quantum, against AES (or any
> cipher), must, at some point, leverage a specific property of the
> cipher. This is not the case here.

The original paper was withdrawn but can still be accessed here https://eprint.iacr.org/archive/2022/948/20220722:134301.